# Incorrect displayfield value formatting

Tags: extjs4

I have a form with a table layout, inside each cell is a `displayfield` with no value when the form is initialised. The values are added later in a loadData function.

I am passing in an array of data to the loadData function and calling `form.setValues()`. All of the data items are simple strings, however some of them have a space eg "my data".

My problem is that when the `setValue()` method sets the `displayfield` `value`, it treats the space as if it were a newline character and puts the follow piece of the string on the line below the first piece.

The cells are more than big enough to accomodate the sizes of the strings so there should be no wordwrap. I thought of trying to set the table row height so the `setValue()` method wouldn't change it but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Does anyone have anyidea on how to fix this?

Here is my code:

```js
initComponent: function() {
    this.dockedItems = [
        { 
            xtype: form,
            layout: {
                type: 'table',
                columns: 4
            },
            defaults:{
                xtype:'displayfield',
                labelWidth: 120
            },
            items:[
                {
                  fieldLabel: 'My Field',
                  name: 'myField'
                },
            //... more items added here
            ],
        }
    ];
    this.callParent(arguments); // other docked items added in parent
},


loadData : function(record, parent) {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    var formItem = this.dockedItems.items[0];
    var form = formItem.getForm();
    form.setValues(record.data);
},
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Do you really need to put the form inside the dockedItems, couldn't you put it in the items config, because dockeditems is generaly used for toolbars so the default layout is either vbox or hbox, which may cause those problems

Comment: Unfortunatly I do, but I have decided to abandon the table idea after all and use a hbox layout and some panels instead like you've suggested. Cheers.

Comment: I would check to make sure you truly have a space character and not a newline, and that the width doesn't cause automatic wrapping. Also, setting the row/cell height probably wouldn't help it not to wrap but more likely would just cut it off.

Answer (score 0):

This IS a problem with width of each item, initially your values are empty and table is rendered with field width more or less equal to field label. Unfortunately Ext table layout doesn't have setting to calculate table cell widths to equally divide its panel width (or I couldn't find one). Never the less you can set default "displayfields" width that will force table layout to render cells bigger initially. Something like this:

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: {
                type: 'table',
                columns: 3
            },
            defaults:{
                xtype:'displayfield',
                labelWidth: 120,
                width: 240
            },
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'My Field',
                name: 'myField'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Home',
                name: 'home_score'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Visitor',
                name: 'visitor_score'
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Update',
                handler: function() {
                    this.up('form').getForm().setValues({
                        myField: 'My text field with white spaces',
                        home_score: '10 123.12',
                        visitor_score: '150 123.789'
                    });
                    this.up('form').forceComponentLayout();
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Pay attention to `this.up('form').forceComponentLayout();` line in button handler function, it will force panel to redo its layout after form data is changed.

You posted [this created jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbgoran/xPXUW/) so you can play live with it.